# How to convert "yyyy-MM-dd" format present in JavaScript file to "dd/MM/yyyy" and "MM/dd/yyyy" format in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to convert "2020-08-02" present in JavaScript file to "08/02/2020" and "02/08/2020" in html file without using new Date() function in JavaScript file.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Split the date and re-arrange it?

Comment: What does the Javascript code look like? What attempt have you made to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
const dateStr = '2020-08-02'
const dateSplits = dateStr.split('-')
const USDate = `${dateSplits[1]}/${dateSplits[2]}/${dateSplits[0]}`
const nonUSDate = `${dateSplits[2]}/${dateSplits[1]}/${dateSplits[0]}`

console.log('Original Date str', dateStr)
console.log('US Formatted Date', USDate)
console.log('Non US Formatted Date', nonUSDate)
```

**Angular Js Example - Using Date Filter / Pipe**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-2gtexq

**Ref**: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Hi Sapun,

Is there any way where i can use date filter in HTML file to convert "2020-08-02'' to dd/MM/yyyy fomat

Comment: what do you mean by `date filter` ? if you are referring to this, `https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date` seems possible. 
We call this behavior `pipes` in Angular 2+

Comment: Yes you can do that, check the example

Comment: yes, i saw that example using $ctrl. But what if the date is inside an array of objects

Comment: For Example: 
$scope.data=[{ name:"yyy",date:"2020-08-02"},
{name:"zzz",date:"2020-08-04"}
]

Comment: Now can we use $ctrl?

Comment: @Vinay the question is related to date rendering. It will be better to address the new query in a separate question or else the answers will not be related to the original question. I believe now the latter question is more **angularjs** related